# TinyMCE: j is undefined

Tags: javascript, tinymce

What's wrong with this code? I get "J is undefined message" after insert the image. I think this happends while i try to close itself.

```
var ImageDialog = 
{
    init : function()
    {
        var f = document.forms[0], ed = tinyMCEPopup.editor;
        e = ed.selection.getNode();
        if (e.nodeName == 'IMG')
        {
            f.src.value = ed.dom.getAttrib(e, 'src');
        }
    },

    update : function()
    {
        var f = document.forms[0], nl = f.elements, ed = tinyMCEPopup.editor, args = {}, el;

        tinyMCEPopup.restoreSelection();

        if (f.src.value === '')
        {
            if (ed.selection.getNode().nodeName == 'IMG')
            {
                ed.dom.remove(ed.selection.getNode());
                ed.execCommand('mceRepaint');
            }

            tinyMCEPopup.close();
            return;
        }

        tinymce.extend(args,
        {
            src : f.src.value
        });

        el = ed.selection.getNode();

        if (el && el.nodeName == 'IMG')
        {
            ed.dom.setAttribs(el, args);
            tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceRepaint');
            tinyMCEPopup.editor.focus();
        }
        else
        {
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="'+args['src']+'" id="_mce_temp_rob" alt="" />', {skip_undo : 1});
            ed.undoManager.add();
            ed.focus();
            ed.selection.select(ed.dom.select('#_mce_temp_rob')[0]);
            ed.selection.collapse(0);
            ed.dom.setAttrib('_mce_temp_rob', 'id', '');
            tinyMCEPopup.storeSelection();
        }

        tinyMCEPopup.close();
    },

    getImageData : function()
    {
        var f = document.forms[0];
        this.preloadImg = new Image();
        this.preloadImg.src = tinyMCEPopup.editor.documentBaseURI.toAbsolute(f.src.value);
    }
};

tinyMCEPopup.onInit.add(ImageDialog.init, ImageDialog);
```

Comment: I assume you're using a compressed version of TinyMCE. Can you try with the uncompressed version and update the question with the new error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a tinymce bug. Internally, the tinymce code uses a `<span id="mce_marker"></span>` to remember the caret-position when pasting. when validating the resulting fragment, after the paste, the span is deemed invalid and removed, thus breaking the code by removing the marker.
This issue will be fixed in the next official tinymce minor release. There are some workarounds for this kind of issue. One is to add to add `id` and `mce-data-type` attribute to `spans` [as valid elements (init setting)](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements). Example:

```
// The valid_elements option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.
    valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style]," +
    "a[name|href|target|title]," +
    "#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u" +
    "-span[data-mce-type]",
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I found it too.. It's a Tinymce bug.